# Android Studio Emulator Not Running. Codes are OK

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app for my company but I cannot see my work since my emulator is not running.

Here is my code below. There are no errors. I am running this in android studio.

It runs on some apps but I tried inputting my code then it does not work.

Please Help

```
 package com.example.tankoverfill;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button calc;

TextView tv_heightfills = findViewById(R.id.tv_heightfills);
TextView tv_timefills = findViewById(R.id.tv_timefills);

EditText flow, areas, heights, densities, heightones, cvs;
int x1,y1,w1,a1, x2,y2,w2,a2,g;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    flow = findViewById(R.id.flow);
    areas = findViewById(R.id.areas);
    heights =  findViewById(R.id.heights);
    densities =  findViewById(R.id.densities);
    heightones  =  findViewById(R.id.heightones);
    cvs  =  findViewById(R.id.cvs);
    calc = findViewById(R.id.calc);



    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        x1 = Integer.parseInt(flow.getText().toString());
        y1 = Integer.parseInt(cvs.getText().toString());
        w1 = Integer.parseInt(densities.getText().toString());
         g = (int) 9.8;

        a1 = (x1 / (y1*w1*g));

        tv_heightfills.setText(a1);

        }
    });

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            x2 = Integer.parseInt(areas.getText().toString());
            y2 = Integer.parseInt(cvs.getText().toString());
           w2 = Integer.parseInt(densities.getText().toString());
             g = (int) 9.8;

    a2 = (x1 / (y1*w1*g));

    tv_timefills.setText(a2);



  }
 });

 }
 }
```

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.example.tankoverfill, PID: 10137
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tankoverfill/com.example.tankoverfill.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback
>   android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
>           at com.example.tankoverfill.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:15)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
>           at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10137 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello two of the errors you have in your code are:

first error that you must link the two textview to xml inside onCreate() method

**error**

```
TextView tv_heightfills = findViewById(R.id.tv_heightfills);
TextView tv_timefills = findViewById(R.id.tv_timefills);
```

**correct**

```
TextView tv_heightfills;
TextView tv_timefills;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv_heightfills = findViewById(R.id.tv_heightfills);
    tv_timefills = findViewById(R.id.tv_timefills);

    ....

}
```

Second error is setting int value to the textview setText() method

so it should be:

```
tv_heightfills.setText(String.valueOf(a1));
```

same for

```
tv_timefills.setText(String.valueOf(a2));
```

Comment: WOW!, Thank you so much! Got it to work in the app. You are a genius!

Need only now to adjust the constraints.